# Increment id (num facture) in my controller without using IDENTITY

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have homework in which I have a database with 4 tables (`client, books, facture, detailsFacture`).

In my `facture` table I have `numFacture` column that needs to be incremented for each client but not with the `IDENTITY` in my database. I have to increment it in my controller.

I tried to add each client in a list and then increment `numFacture` like you can see in my code.

The code of my method in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Paiement(Client client)
{
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains("Panier"))
            {
                this._panier = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Panier>(HttpContext.Session.GetString("Panier"));
            }

            // Calculate price
            double prixAvantTaxe = 0;
            double prixTaxe = 0;
            double montantTaxe = 0.15;

            List<AchatLivreViewModel> Livre = _panier.ListeElements;
            prixAvantTaxe = Livre.Sum(item => item.Prix);
            prixTaxe = Livre.Sum(item => item.Prix * montantTaxe + item.Prix);
            ViewBag.SansTaxe = prixAvantTaxe;
            ViewBag.taxe = prixTaxe;

            // Count number of books in cart
            ViewBag.taillepanier = _panier.ListeElements.Count();

            // Insert client into DB
            List<Client> listeclient = new List<Client>();
            this._context.InsertClients(client);
            listeclient.Add(client);

            // Insert facture into DB
            //int numFacture = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < listeclient.Count; i++)
            {
                this._context.InsertFacture(i, client.Telephone, prixAvantTaxe, prixTaxe);
            }

            //foreach (Client c in listeclient)
            //{
            //    this._context.InsertFacture(numFacture, client.Telephone, prixAvantTaxe, prixTaxe);
            //    numFacture++;
            //}

            return View("Confirmation");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorViewModel erreur = new ErrorViewModel { ControllerName = "Achat", ActionName = "Paiement", ErrorMessage = "Une erreur s'est produite lors du paiement" };
            return View("Erreur", erreur);
        }
}
```

So I would like to increment the number for each client but it didn't work and I get an error because `numFacture` is a primary key.

Comment: You need to get the Maximum value of `numFacture` from the database and then insert new values starting from there...

Comment: hi 
thank you but what do you means when you said i need to get de Maximum value of numFacture ?

here my Facture table :

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Factures](
 [NumFacture] [nchar](4) NOT NULL,
 [Telephone] [nchar] (14)NOT NULL,
 [Montant_hors_taxe] [money]NOT NULL,
 [Montant_taxe] [money]NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Facture] PRIMARY KEY ([NumFacture])
 )
GO

Comment: When you want to insert new row, you do not know what is the last value inserted for `numFacture` in the table. `numFacture` is a primary key column so you can not insert the same value again. So you need to get the last value for `numFacture` from the table and increment it by one to insert in row into the table. Also if you want to store numeric values to the `numFacture` you should have INT datatype for that column, not `nchar`

Comment: Any reason you can not use the `IDENTITY` on primary key column?

Comment: Your homework is saying that you have to NOT use an identity column? That seems like a bad practice... If you try to do it with your code, and if your code is called two or more times at exactly the same time, you could end up with duplicate IDs.

Comment: Thank you 
my homework not directly tell that i cant use identity but usually the teacher write all what we have to do and the only think its was wrote for numfacture was primary key and not null and when he want idenity he specify it

Comment: Getting the maximum value and then adding to it is a bad idea so I hope the instructor is not trying to teach you to do that. Fortunately, there's a kind of object called a [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) that lets you accomplish same thing. `NEXT VALUE FOR <sequence-name>` will give you the next value and never duplicate it (notwithstanding cycling, should it ever get to that point and it's enabled).